# g_mass_storage issues in 4.9 kernel

Tags: raspbian, usb, kernel, raspbian-lite

I previously had the Mass Storage gadget mainly working with the April version of Jessie (kernel 4.4.50+). Unfortunately it wasn't working on all systems so I thought it would be worth updating to see if a new kernel would work.

I did an `apt-get upgrade` but that failed to boot. I then did a fresh Jessie Lite install (4.9.35+, July 2017).

I then went through the usual setup process

```
$ echo "dtoverlay=dwc2" | sudo tee -a /boot/config.txt
```

no problems after reboot

```
$ echo "dwc2" | sudo tee -a /etc/module
```

no problems after reboot

```
$ echo "g_mass_storage" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

kernel panic on boot - happened everytime

I managed to regain access by manually altering `config.txt` on the SD card to comment out the dwc2 overlay. This let me get back into the system. I then did an `rpi-update` to 4.9.36+, however this then had the same issue when I re-enabled the dwc2 overlay (this is presumably why my `apt-get upgrade` version ran into issues)

Does anyone have any ideas what has changed that is stopping this from now working? Unfortunately as I can't get SSH access when it crashes on boot I can't paste the full kernel panic dump (unless it's stored somewhere in a log I can access on next successful boot??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so if I boot with dtoverlay in `config.txt` and dwc2 in `/etc/module` set then try to manually start g_mass_storage with `sudo modprobe …` then it seems to work, in a way that starting it in `/etc/modules` caused a crash.

I don't quite understand what has changed (given the previous system worked fine with the older kernel), but at least it seems to load with the latest Jessie Lite now!

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.